# Consider changing the reputation's link from the privileges page to the audit

Tags: feature-request, privileges, reputation-audit, header

The new drop down for clicking your display name includes a link to the privileges page. This makes it redundant with the functionality of clicking your displayed reputation.

I've always found it curious that we chose that as where to click, but at any rate, now that we have a different slot to put it, I think we can move the reputation to link to something more useful - the audit page on `/reputation`.

I know things are still under construction, but I think that when it comes to accessing things, the reputation audit is a far more common need than the privileges page. The reputation audit is subject to updating on a frequent basis, whereas the meat of the privileges page doesn't update without the launching of new features. Even tracking when you reach new privilege levels, it takes increasing amounts of reputation to hit each new privilege, which means that checking for that will just occur far slower.

Given that, I think the audit has more use as a one-click action than the privileges page. Could we change the reputation to link to it, instead?

Comment: Is there a link to the old page the envelope used to link to?  That's what I'd like to see fixed before this.

Comment: @jjnguy [That page is going to be revised](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope/82688#82688). Presumeably, once the newer page is deployed, we'll get access to that.

Comment: This is, more or less, [what I suggested in that topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope/82748#82748). Assuming this final rep management page doesn't suck, I'd go for this.